# Multithreading in IOS SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, sprite-kit

I did not find any questions related to SpriteKit multithreading. I think this would be a good chance to get some suggestions.

I am creating a game using SpriteKit, which is controlled by voice. So I have another thread to detect voice. I use a delegate to communicate between my audio thread and my SKScene. However I can tell that it has a few seconds delay. I want to find a best way to control the game by sound.

SoundDetect.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
@protocol SoundDetectDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)update_from_sound: (SKSpriteNode*) node;
@end
@interface SoundDetect : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SoundDetectDelegate> delegate;
-(void)beat;
```

SoundDetect.m
I have something like following when I detect the sound. My goal is to update my SKScene

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

      SKSpriteNode * node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"2.png"];
      [self.delegate update_from_sound:node];
});
```

HelloScene.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import "SoundDetect.h"
@interface HelloScene : SKScene <SoundDetectDelegate>

@end
```

HelloScene.m
   -(void) update_from_sound:(SKSpriteNode*) node{

```
   [self addChild:node];
}
```

What is a typical way to do if I want to control SKScene from another thread.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that multithreading is the source of the delay. If you use the voice recognition on the main thread as well, is the delay gone?

Comment: Measure the time between the voice being recognised, the delegate method being called, and the delegatge method being executed to see where the delay is.